# Character counter for textarea in webform

Tags: 7

I am relatively new to drupal. I have webform module and webform validation module installed. I was able to limit the number of characters in webform textarea using webform validation. However, this module does not support character counter for the fields. I have looked at this solution http://drupal.org/node/1459650#comment-5699952 which using maxlength module, but it is very unclear . I am planning to write a module implement hook_webform_component_info_alter(&$components) to add jquery or javascript on to the webform textarea field. Is this a correct way. If so or If not how would i do that?

Answer (score 1):

For webforms use the [Webform Countdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_countdown) module instead of maxlength. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Provides a textarea component for Drupal webforms with a configurable, twitter-style dynamic word or character count.